# Issues making div height 100% with all parent containers at 100%

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a `div`'s height stretch out to 100% but everything I have tried has failed.

I **HAVE** looked around the web for solutions on this, and have tried every single one, yet I am still doing something wrong.

Here is my code: http://jsbin.com/elijuh/3/edit

Output: http://jsbin.com/elijuh/3

I have made every other `div` above the `div`, I want to stretch to also adjust to 100% which is what everyone on the Google is suggesting, but still nothing.

The two divs I'm trying to adjust is quick_analy_main and quick_analy_graph.

I know it is probably really easy to do, but I can't figure it out.

Can someone tell me where I've gone wrong please.

Comment: Can you tell which `div` you want to expand to a 100%? There are so many `div`s there! :)

Comment: Ooops, sorry about that. The two divs I'm trying to adjust is quick_analy_main and quick_analy_graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I fixed the issue: http://jsbin.com/elijuh/13/edit

Answer (score 0):

When you set height to 100%, you always have to ask the question "100% of what?". It's always the height of the parent, so what is the parent in this case? It all bubbles up to the body element here. So what is the body set to? Nothing. Set it to 100% and see what happens. But html must also have a height set because it is the parent of the body.

Comment: body is already set to 100%. sorry for not mentioning it. Just didnt add it in the jsbin example. I just tried it in the example and its still not working.

Comment: Tuva's one did the trick. I needed to use body, html{height:100%}. Thanks anyway.